# Lazy-loaded e formas de carregamento angular

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Olá boa tarde a todos...

Sou desenvolvedor angular a algum tempo, e já me deparei com duas forma de realizar o famoso Lazy-loaded, que são:

```
{ path: 'rota', loadChildren: '../module/function.module#FunctionModule'}
```

e

```
{ path: 'rota', loadChildren: () => import('../module/function.module').then(m => m.FunctionModule)}
```

eu procurei na internet a diferença dos dois porém nunca encontrei nada referente!

Gostaria de saber se realmente existe uma diferença entre essas duas chamadas, ou são apenas formas diferentes de fazer a mesma coisa??

De qualquer forma agradeço desde já...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente a primeira forma é a antiga que usávamos até o `Angular 7` e a segunda é a nova forma introduzida no `Angular 8`. A segunda acaba sendo mais confiável, pois a sua IDE consegue te ajudar mais na importação, é o padrão do [EC2020](https://www.infoq.com/br/news/2019/07/angular-8-release/) e mais simples de entender por quem não está ambientado com o framework.

É interessante notar a motivação de tais formas, na época que até o Angular 7 foi desenvolvido poucos browsers suportavam o `import`, por esse motivo escolheram o caminho da primeira forma. [Aqui eles explicam mais detalhado](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#loadchildren-string-syntax).

```
{ path: 'rota', loadChildren: '../module/function.module#FunctionModule'}
```

Porém como hoje ele já é suportado por vários browsers eles resolveram adotar, seguindo assim o padrão do `ES2020`

```
{ path: 'rota', loadChildren: () => import('../module/function.module').then(m => m.FunctionModule)}
```

Hoje ainda as duas formas funcionam, porém a feita com `string` está depreciada, provavelmente nas próximas versões deve ser descontinuada.

Answer (score 1):

A primeira forma

```
{ path: 'rota', loadChildren: '../module/function.module#FunctionModule'}
```

É a forma mais antiga de como era feito quando saiu o Angular2, no entanto por ser um path dentro de uma string, é mais sucetivel a erro. No entanto por motivos de legado se mantem funcionando.

Essa forma aqui é mais nova:

```
{ path: 'rota', loadChildren: () => import('../module/function.module').then(m => m.FunctionModule)}
```

Ela garante que você está importando certo. Por exemplo vc pode apertar ctrl mais FunctionModule e ele vai te levar ao modulo pra você ver se é realmente o modulo que você quer. Sendo assim fica mais explicito os imports.

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente.

Só para confirmar, isso não leva nenhum ganho de performance na aplicação?

Comment: Não mas eu refatorei pro modo novo na minha aplicação porque esses legados nunca se sabe até quando eles vão dar suporte.